# jQuery UI Slider - stop at certain points and show hidden item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to build out a navigation slider, and am at a loss. What I really need is a slider that stops at specific points, and shows a hidden item based on the point it stops at.

I have built out a very simple example of what I mean in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4abfep8/35/).

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="second">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="third">Slide 3</li>
  </ul>
</div> 
<div id="slider-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
    <li>Nav 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

So what needs to happen is the first "Slide" is shown by default, but when you slide the bar and it reaches "Nav 2" on the bar above (so essentially every 100px would be fine) than "Slide 1" would be hidden and "Slide 2" would appear. This functionality needs to work in reverse as well.

I haven't been able to find anything that really functions like what I need. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: see this example: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/qvotoqkb/4/ or in the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check my test. https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/qvotoqkb/3/
You need define the width and range of values in slide bar. But it's a way to solve.

html (you need include jquery, jqueryui and jqueryuicss)

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="slide1" class="first">Slide 1</li>
    <li id="slide2">Slide 2</li>
    <li id="slide3">Slide 3</li>
  </ul>
</div> 
<div id="slider-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
    <li>Nav 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div> 
<form id="reservation">
  <label style="display:none"for="minbeds">Minimum number of beds</label>
  <select name="minbeds" id="minbeds" style="display:none">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
    var select = $( "#minbeds" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 7,
      range: "min",
      value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#slider-wrapper ul li").hide();
        $("#slide"+ui.value).show();
        console.log(ui.value);
        select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
      }
    });
    $( "#minbeds" ).change(function() {
      slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
  });
```

and css

```
#slider-wrapper ul li {display:none;}
#slider-wrapper ul li.first {display:block;}

#slider-nav {margin:25px auto; text-align:left;}
#slider-nav ul {padding:0; margin:0; height:0; border-bottom:5px solid #000;}
#slider-nav ul li {display:inline-block; background:red; padding:5px; color:#fff; margin:0 15px 0 0; width:80px; text-align:center;}

#slider {margin:50px 0 0 10px;}
```

Comment: Other options is use slide range, eg: if you have 3 div with 100px per div, define the slider width in 300px and range values of 1 to 300. When you scroll, get value, if value is <= 100, show slide 1, if value between 100 to 200, slide2 and etc.. see: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up a change event listener to your slider. Then based on the value you can use a switch statement to show/hide the correct pieces.

Example:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 1,
  min: 1,
  max: 3,
  step: 1,
  change: function(event, ui) {
      switch(ui.value) {
          case 1:
              // do something
              break;
          case 2:
              // do something different
              break;
          default:
              // do something else
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer as well!